# Zen theme created new region but it is not pushing other divs down when it has content added to it - css related

Tags: theming

Hello i am currently using 7.23 core version of drupal and have a customized version of the zen theme that i am using, in my markup i have added my own theme region regions

```
[video]          = Featured video
```

the way my theme is setup i have 3 equal width columns

First sidebar | main content | second sidebar|

but what i am trying to achieve is something like this

First sidebar |------------Video ----------- |
First sidebar | main content | second sidebar|

i have achieved the look stated above the only problem now is that when i add content to the video region it will not push the main content and second sidebar  down accordingly.
any help with this is much appreciated i hope this doesn't get to much hate as i know its more of a css issue i think more than anything, thank you in advance!

```
.two-sidebars #content {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    margin-left: 33.45%;
    margin-right: -97%;
    margin-top:475px
}
/* Span 1 column, starting in 1st column from left. */
.two-sidebars .region-sidebar-first {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    margin-left: -1%;
    margin-right: -25%;

}
/* Span 1 column, starting in 5th column from left. */
.two-sidebars .region-sidebar-second {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    margin-left: 60.33%;
    margin-right: -100%;
    margin-top:475px

}
.two-sidebars #video {
    height:auto;
    float:right;
    background:#fff;
    width:63.5%;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

above is the following css for the regions